# Shape does not invert color relative to background when position changed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to achieve a color inversion effect on a smaller circle that's on top of a larger circle when it's dragged to the edge of the larger circle. The smaller circle is supposed to invert its colors to provide contrast against the background. However, I'm not getting the expected result. The colors don't seem to invert when I drag the smaller circle to the edge.

Here's the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var location             = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var innerCircleLocation  = CGPoint.zero
    @GestureState private var fingerLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    private let bigCircleRadius: CGFloat    = 150

    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in

            // some code here
            
            ZStack {

                // Larger circle
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: bigCircleRadius * 2, height: bigCircleRadius * 2)

                // Smaller circle
                Circle()     
                    .colorInvert()  // < --- 
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                    .position(innerCircleLocation)
                    .gesture(fingerDrag)

            }
            // Initialize the location and innerCircleLocation
            .onAppear {
                location = CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                innerCircleLocation = location
            }

            // some other code here

            }
        }
}
```

And here's what was shown on the simulator:

[image]

It seems like `colorInvert()` doesn't actively update the color value of the smaller circle when it gets moved. What could be done to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your code to make a minimal reproducible example: Remove anything that is not neccessary and add anything to make your code work self-contained. This will enable readers to help you.

Comment: `colorInvert` changes the color of the `Circle` it is attached to. It doesn't take into account the colors of views below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple workaround: a `.mask` modifier that masks the existing smaller inverted color circle based on the larger circle, and make another small circle of same size that follows the existing smaller circle(same position modifier) underneath the larger circle:

```swift
ZStack {
    // Circle that follows the inverted color circle
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
        .position(innerCircleLocation)

    // Larger circle
    Circle()
        .frame(width: bigCircleRadius * 2, height: bigCircleRadius * 2)

    // Smaller circle
    Circle()
        .colorInvert()
        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
        .position(innerCircleLocation)
        .gesture(fingerDrag)
        .mask(Circle().frame(width: bigCircleRadius * 2, height: bigCircleRadius * 2)) // Add this line
}
```

which gives the expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`colorInvert()` works differently than you may expect.

From Apple documentation [`colorInvert()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/colorinvert()):

> The `colorInvert()` modifier inverts all of the colors in a view so that each color displays as its complementary color. For example, blue converts to yellow, and white converts to black.

In other words, the modifier does not compare each overlayed pixel's colors, it just takes each of a view's `Color` value and computes the complementary color.

---

To get your expected results, here is a simple approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var bigCircleRadius: CGFloat = 150
    @State private var smallCircleRadius: CGFloat = 75/2
    @State private var smallCircleXOffset: CGFloat = -125
    @State private var smallCircleYOffset: CGFloat = -75
    
    @State private var objectColor: Color = .black
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                // Smaller circle
                Circle()     // under & outside
                    .frame(width: smallCircleRadius * 2, height: smallCircleRadius * 2)
                    .offset(x: smallCircleXOffset, y: smallCircleYOffset)
                    .foregroundColor(objectColor)
                
                // Larger circle
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: bigCircleRadius * 2, height: bigCircleRadius * 2)
                    .foregroundColor(objectColor)
                
                // Smaller circle in big frame
                Group {
                    Circle()     // on top & inside
                        .frame(width: smallCircleRadius * 2, height: smallCircleRadius * 2)
                        .offset(x: smallCircleXOffset, y: smallCircleYOffset)
                        .foregroundColor(objectColor)
                        .colorInvert()
                }
                .frame(width: bigCircleRadius * 2, height: bigCircleRadius * 2)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            .padding(smallCircleRadius)
            .background(objectColor.colorInvert()) // not necessary, only here to match the given example.
        }
    }
}
```

There are now 2 small circles on the same position, controlled by the `offset()` modifier. One is higher, one is lower in the `ZStack`'s order than the big circle.

The lower circle is showing the part of the resulting small circle that is outside of the big circle in the chosen `objectColor`.

The higher small circle is showing the part inside the big circle using `invertedColor()` in the complementary color of `objectColor`.